# Исключение c Long.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java

Необходимо написать метод который считывает из файла числа и находит их сумму, если сумма больше Long.MAX_VALUE.выбросить исключение.
Вопрос: как проверить Long.MAX_VALUE и какой класс использовать в самом методе?

Сам метод:

```
 public static long findSum(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, AccessDeniedException, BadFormatException, MaxValueException, IOException {
        String result1 = readFirstLine(new File("C:\\input.txt"));
        String file1 = result1.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        long x = Long.parseLong(file1);
        long i = 0;
        while (x != 0) {
            i = i + x % 10;
            x = x / 10;
            if (i > Long.MAX_VALUE)
                throw new MaxValueException("Cумма превышает допустимых значения Long.MAX_VALUE");
        }
        return i;
```

Comment: а числа положительные в файле?

Comment: да числа в файле вида " 1 2 3 4 5 6 "

Comment: Вдумайтесь в эту строчку `if (i > Long.MAX_VALUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь тем соображением, что `a + b > c`, только если `a > c - b`.

Т.е. перед добавлением к сумме `S` нового числа `X` проверьте, что текущая сумма не больше чем `MAX_VALUE - X`.

Answer (score 0):

Если нет соревнования на скорость, то работать с `BigDecimal`, и потом сконвертить `longValueExact`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#longValueExact()